# VHDL syntax error using when

Tags: vhdl, quartus

I have the following code:

```
DATA_LCD <= DATA_ROM when SW(1)='0' or char_code<97 or char_code>122 else
                 std_logic_vector(char_code-32); -- no modification in this code
                     DATA_ROM when SW(2)='0' else
                     std_logic_vector(char_code+1);
```

But when i try to compile it i get following errors:

> Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at LCD_FSM.vhd(57) near text "=";  expecting "(", or "'", or "."
>
> Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at LCD_FSM.vhd(57) near text "when";  expecting "(", or "'", or "."

How can I fix it?

Comment: It could be good to have more information, especially on the signal definition. But basically the second `DATA_ROM` just comes from nowhere, I don't get what you're trying to do there.

Comment: No more information needed. The third line is the start of a new (malformed) statement. (There was probably supposed to be another "when" clause on the second line)

Comment: Rows 3 and 4 just look like a (combinational) expression. Should it be driving something?

Comment: So what does SW(1) and SW(2) signify?  The first condition expression appears to relate to an HD44780U type LCD controller (2 or 4 line LCD display). Fixing it requires understanding what it's supposed to do - you have two else condition values shown.

Answer (score 0):

Brian is right, line 3 is a new (malformed) statement.
You forgot to put another DATA_LCD <= at the beginning of it.

```
DATA_LCD <= DATA_ROM when SW(2)='0' else std_logic_vector(char_code+1);
```

Comment: I don't get your edit. The code you added does not match the OP question. Furthermore, this question is 16 months old!